# How to pass arguments into JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to pass a value to a Jquery function. 
Below is the Javascript sample code. I want to convert this javascript function to a jquery function. How can I pass the state name into a jquery onclick function?

```
<a onclick="showState('state_name')">ADD STATE </a>

 function showState(state_name){
 openbox_state(state_name);
 }
```

please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't really make it clear whether you have a series of anchors to add different states, or...?

If you do, you can do something like this to record the appropriate state name for each link:

```
<a data-stateName="state_name">ADD STATE </a>
```

And then in JS, with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[data-stateName]").click(function() {
        openbox_state( $(this).attr("data-stateName") );
    });
});
```

This removes the inline JavaScript from your html, and then uses jQuery to bind a click handler only to those `<a>` elements that have a `data-stateName` attribute. The handler then gets the value of that attribute to pass to the `openbox_state()` function.

The document ready handler ensures that the anchor click binding doesn't happen until the document actually is ready, i.e., after the elements have been parsed and can be accessed from JS. (You don't need a ready handler if you put your JS in a script block at the end of the body element.)

Comment: You could also `$(this).data('stateName')` if you so desired.

Comment: @muistooshort - True. I didn't do so because I'm in the habit of using `.data()` only to retrieve values previously set with `.data()`, not for attribute values. It doesn't matter in this case, but I don't like the way `.data()` attempts automatic type conversion when used to retrieve html attributes.

Comment: I hear you on the "software pretending to be smarter than it is" part, I prefer honest and consistent stupidity :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
  $('#MyID').click(function () {

        var StateName = $(this).text();
        showState(StateName);       
   });
```

And then for the HTML, you could put some ID like this:

```
<a id="MyID">ADD STATE </a>
```

Or, if you have many states (which I assume is what you're trying to do) then you could reference the link by CSS class like this:

```
<a class="StateSelector">ADD STATE </a>
```

And then your jquery code becomes:

```
$('.StateSelector').click(function () {

      var StateName = $(this).text();
      showState(StateName);          
});
```

To wire up the event handling, you can put the jquery code in the document ready function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.StateSelector').click(function () {

          var StateName = $(this).text();
          showState(StateName);          
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide the corresponding code for this line, please          <a onclick="showState('state_name')">ADD STATE </a>

Comment: There's no need for onclick="showState(...), jquery handles the event for you. You might want to put some ID in your HTML to reference the link; see edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple `a` with different arguments like this.

```
<a onclick="showState('Delhi')">ADD STATE</a>
<a onclick="showState('Punjab')">ADD STATE</a>
<a onclick="showState('Gujrat')">ADD STATE</a>

function showState(state_name){
 openbox_state(state_name);
}
```

then you can use custom attributes like this

```
<a state="Delhi">ADD STATE</a>
<a state="Punjab">ADD STATE</a>
<a state="Gujrat">ADD STATE</a>

$('a').click(function () {
   var StateName = $(this).attr("state");
   openbox_state(StateName);
});
```

Comment: I think data attributes (`<a data-state="...">` and `$(this).data('state')`) would be better and would leave you with valid HTML to boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<a onclick="showState()" id="florida">ADD STATE </a>

 function showState(state_name){
    var state_name = $(this).attr('id')
    openbox_state(state_name);
}
```

This function will retrieve the "id" value from the  link. You can then pass the value onto your "openbox_state()" function. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a>Montana</a>

$('a').on('click', function(){
     var state = this.text ;   // OR $(this).text();   OR   $(this).html();
     showState(state);
});
```